# nonvanishing of global theta lifting from U(1) to U(1?)

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

I understanding nonvanishing of theta lifting, either global or local, is a difficult and open problem. But I wanna know if there is an answer for the following simplest case.

Let $E/F$ be a quadratic extension of number fields, and let $V,W$ be 1-dimensional hermitian, skew-hermitian spaces over $E$ respectively, then we have isometry group $U(V)$ and $U(W)$. They form a dual pair. Then one may consider the global theta lifting $\Theta(\chi)$ of $U(V)(\mathbb{A}_E)$ of a character $\chi$ of $U(W)(\mathbb{A}_E)$.

Question: When will $\Theta(\chi)$ be nonvanishing? Is there a characterization of nonvanishing?

The corresponding local question has been settled. For example, in the p-adic case, the nonvanishing of a character of $U(W)$ to $U(V)$ can be characterized in terms of certain invariants, as in the paper 'Theta dichotomy for unitary groups ' by Harris-Kudal-Sweet.

I'm interested in the global counterpart, much appreciated for any answer/references. Sorry if this question is not appropriate here.